# Fixed Windows 7 with BCDBoot and MBR. I now get ACTIVATE: Error Code 0xc0004e003

Tags: windows-7, software-activation

I fixed the PC running Windows 7, using "bcdboot C:\Windows", and the computer software thinks I reinstalled the software? 
Says I have 3 days to Activate now I get Error Code 0xc0004e003. 
It took me a couple days to fix this mess. The software has been in this PC since 2009. Any suggestions?
Anybody have suggestions, I would appreciate the help. 
Is it time to leave this whole product behind? Oh, It is a Dell OEM.

Comment: Use Method C on this page>>>>>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/931276/error-message-when-you-try-to-activate-windows-7-or-windows-vista-an-e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Windows copy is activated using MBR patch.

If it is genuine, consider flashing BIOS with correct SLIC table.